# Need instructions on data.frame transformation in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like attachment1, how can I transform it into the data.frame in attachment2?[attachment1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M47FG.png).     [attachment2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h67uZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

letting your data name as `df`,

```
df %>%
  reshape2::melt(value.name = "fruit", measure.var = c("a", "b", "c", "d")) %>%
  na.omit %>% rename( basket = variable)

   basket  fruit
1       a  apple
2       a orange
5       a  peach
10      b  peach
15      c  peach
19      d banana
```